# loop over object with jQuery.each()

Tags: jquery, each

I have an JSON object in this format

```
var data = [
        { "label" : "January"  }, { "value"  : 10  }, { "barcolor" : "rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "February" }, { "value"  : 20  }, { "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "October"  }, { "value"  : 100 }, { "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "November" }, { "value"  : 80  }, { "barcolor" : "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "December" }, { "value"  : 20  }, { "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "January"  }, { "value"  : 70  }, { "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)" }
    ];
```

I want to print in combine format like

```
<h1 style="color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.9);">January <em>count: 10</em></h1>
```

these should be 6 h1 or whatever no of "Label", 
BUT MY jQuery going 18 in a loop

```
$.each(data, function(index, val) {
    //console.log('index : ' + index + ' || val : ' + val.label);
    $.each(val, function(i, v) {
    //console.log('i : ' + i + ' || v : ' + v);
        var dhtml = '<h1 style="color:' + val.barcolor + '">' + val.label + '<em>' + val.value + '</em></h1>';
        $('body').append(dhtml);
    });
});
```

not getting desired output 
http://codepen.io/iahmad/pen/BLgJBb

Comment: You should change your json

Comment: That's not JSON. It's an array of objects. JSON is a data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your JSON format and loop, here is working JS (copy to codepen):

```
var data = [
    { "label" : "January", "value"  : 10, "barcolor" : "rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
    { "label" : "February", "value"  : 20, "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.9)" },
    { "label" : "October", "value"  : 100, "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.9)" },
    { "label" : "November",  "value"  : 80, "barcolor" : "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
    { "label" : "December", "value"  : 20,  "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)" },
    { "label" : "January", "value"  : 70,  "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)" }
];

$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    var dhtml = '<h1 style="color:' + val.barcolor + '">' + val.label + '<em>' + val.value + '</em></h1>'
    $('body').append(dhtml);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this and try:

```
var data = [
       { "label" : "January"  ,  "value"  : 10  ,  "barcolor" : "rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
       { "label" : "February" , "value"  : 20  ,  "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.9)" },
       { "label" : "October"  ,  "value"  : 100 ,  "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.9)" },
       { "label" : "November" , "value"  : 80  ,  "barcolor" : "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
       { "label" : "December" ,  "value"  : 20  ,  "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)" },
       { "label" : "January"  ,  "value"  : 70  ,  "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)" }
        ];

$.each(data, function(i, v) {
var dhtml = '<h1 style="color:' + v.barcolor + '">' + v.label + '<em>' + v.value + '</em></h1>'
$('body').append(dhtml);
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON should be in this format :

```
var data = [
        { "label" : "January", "value"  : 10, "barcolor" : "rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "February", "value"  : 20, "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "October", "value"  : 100, "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "November", "value"  : 80, "barcolor" : "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "December", "value"  : 20, "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)" },
        { "label" : "January", "value"  : 70, "barcolor" : "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)" }
    ];
```

And following is the JS code :

```
$.each(data, function(index, val) {
        var dhtml = '<h1 style="color:' + val.barcolor + '">' + val.label + '<em>' + val.value + '</em></h1>'
        $('body').append(dhtml);
});
```